# React Material UI Data Grid onSelectionModelChange with custome pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I am having a trouble using `DataGrid`  `onSelectionModelChange` prop . I can get the current selected rows for a single page, but when I use  `custom` pagination and move to the next page and use  `onSelectionModelChange` again, I lose the previuos `selections`.

```
function DataTable(props, list, count) {

  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1)
  const [selectionModel, setSelectionModel] = React.useState([]);
  const prevSelectionModel = React.useRef(selectionModel);


  let history = useHistory();
  const columns = [#cols here]

  React.useEffect(() => {

    listView(page, newSearch);
   
  }, [page, newSearch]);

  const data = {
    columns: columns,
    rows: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("results"))
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 600, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        autoHeight
        rows={data.rows}
        columns={columns}
        hideFooterPagination={true}
        checkboxSelection
        onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
          setSelectionModel(ids);
          console.log(selectionModel)
        }}
        pageSize={10}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
        // {...data}
      />
      <AppPagination
      setPage={setPage}
      page={page}
      />
    </div>
  );
}


enter code here
```

Answer (score 3):

The props `keepNonExistentRowsSelected` works for your code.
More information to see [Mui data-grid docs](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/) and [github issue](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/4676)

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example for your case : you can watch the console in this sandbox ... not losing selected rows

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66424752/get-row-item-on-checkbox-selection-in-react-material-ui-data-grid]

Comment: im losing the selected rows because im using a custm pagination, with each page change im requesting a new list from the server, In the `useEffect` so this Re renders the page.

Comment: You can use Redux OR local storage to persist selection of rows

Comment: Please include the code on your answer, it shouldn't depend on external links. Answers that depend on an external link may be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Use Props keepNonExistentRowsSelected in DataGrid .
If keepNonExistentRowsSelected props is true , then the selection model will retain selected rows that do not exist. Useful when using server side pagination and row selections need to be retained when changing pages.

```
 <StyledDataGrid
          keepNonExistentRowsSelected/>.
```

[Usage with server-side pagination](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/selection/#usage-with-server-side-pagination)